# Problem calling string manipulation method within linq-to-sql query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having a frustrating issue trying to use LINQ to call a string manipulation method.  I've done lots of searching now and have tried various method to get the line noted as 'FAILS' below to work.  It currently throws an exception.

Some things I've tried:

a) Initially the creation of the concatenated key was in the same query, didn't change anything

b) Converting the non-string fields to strings (another whole can of works with .ToString not working in linq.  String.Concat and String.Format were tried, work ok in some cases but not when you try to refer to that value later on)

c) Using the concat etc instead of the '+' to join the things together.

As you can see it seems fairly tolerant of appending strings to non-strings, but *not* when that method is invoked.

There are lots of rows so I'd prefer not to convert the data to a list/array etc, but if that's the only option then any suggestions appreciated.

Many thanks! - Mark

```
    var vouchers = from v in db.Vouchers
                   select new
                   {
                       v.Amount,
                       v.Due_Date,
                       v.Invoice_Date,
                       v.PO_CC,
                       v.Vendor_No_,
                       v.Invoice_No_,
                       invoiceNumeric = MFUtil.StripNonNumeric(v.Invoice_No_)
                   };


    var keyedvouchers = from vv in vouchers
                        select new
                        {
                            thekey = vv.Vendor_No_ + "Test", // works with normal string
                            thekey2 = vv.Amount + "Test", // works with decimal
                            thekey3 = vv.Invoice_Date + "Test", // works with date
                            thekey4 = vv.invoiceNumeric, // works
                            thekey5 = vv.invoiceNumeric + "Test" // FAILS
                        };
```

-- The method to strip chars ---

```
   public static string StripNonNumeric(string str) 
   {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str) 
        {
            // only append if its withing the acceptable boundaries
            // strip special chars: if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') | || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') | c == '.' || c == '_') 

            // strip any nonnumeric chars
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                {
                sb.Append(c);
                }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

-- The Exception Message--

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Could not translate expression 'Table(Voucher).Select(v => new <>f__AnonymousType0`7(Amount = v.Amount, Due_Date = v.Due_Date, Invoice_Date = v.Invoice_Date, PO_CC = v.PO_CC, Vendor_No_ = v.Vendor_No_, Invoice_No_ = v.Invoice_No_, invoiceNumeric = StripNonNumeric(v.Invoice_No_))).Select(vv => new <>f__AnonymousType1`5(thekey = (vv.Vendor_No_ + "Test"), thekey2 = (Convert(vv.Amount) + "Test"), thekey3 = (Convert(vv.Invoice_Date) + "Test"), thekey4 = vv.invoiceNumeric, thekey5 = (vv.invoiceNumeric + "Test")))' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it tries to build an SQL query of the expression and the `MFUtil.StripNonNumeric` cannot be translated into SQL.

Try returning it first and then convert the reult into a list and then use a second query to convert it.

```
var vouchers_temp = from v in db.Vouchers
               select new
               {
                   v.Amount,
                   v.Due_Date,
                   v.Invoice_Date,
                   v.PO_CC,
                   v.Vendor_No_,
                   v.Invoice_No_
               };


var vouchers = vouchers_temp.ToList().Select( new {
                   Amount,
                   Due_Date,
                   Invoice_Date,
                   PO_CC,
                   Vendor_No_,
                   Invoice_No_,
                   invoiceNumeric = MFUtil.StripNonNumeric(Invoice_No_)
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the advice, I'll try this and advise when I am back near this DB in a day and a half :)

Comment: Many thanks, this did the trick.  I couldn't quite get the 2nd query to work as you had put it, but by separating out the ToList step it worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the hint david, a simple .ToList() in the middle of my chain did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It FAILS to work, because it is not suppose to work.

Create a SQL-side function and call that in the query.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not adept at writing SQL functions but thanks for the idea.